# How to load view from array of filenames in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I have class name scores

```
class Scores extends Front_Controller
{
   public function __construct()
   {
      parent::__construct();
   }
}
```

and method scorecard

```
public function scorecard()
{
   $this->load->view('/Cricket/'.$arpf);
}
```

Where $arpf is

```
array(19) {
  [19]=> string(12) "IND_NZ_NOV01"
  [20]=> string(18) "ZIM_WI_OCT29_NOV02"
  [21]=> string(14) "PAKW_NZW_NOV02"
  ......
  .......
  .....
  .....
  [25]=> string(18) "CAN_NK_OCT30_NOV02"
  [26]=> string(19) "WEL_OTG_OCT30_NOV02"
  [27]=> ....
  .....
  ....
  ...
  string(18) "CD_AKL_OCT30_NOV02"
}
```

I want to load multiple files from cricket folder containing all individuals pages to load

```
Folder structure
application
views
---Cricket
     ----IND_NZ_NOV01.php
    ------ZIM_WI_OCT29_NOV02.php
    ----PAKW_NZW_NOV02.php
..
..
   -----CAN_NK_OCT30_NOV02.php
    ----WEL_OTG_OCT30_NOV02.php
```

I want to load page by

```
site_base_url/scores/scorecard/IND_NZ_NOV01.php
site_base_url/scores/scorecard/ZIM_WI_OCT29_NOV02.php
site_base_url/scores/scorecard/PAKW_NZW_NOV02.php
```

All webpage having different url .

So I want to load every file from cricket folder and filename are stored in array $arpf how to pass all filename in method scorecard to load views for every filename in cricket folder and can be access by going to individual url as

```
site_base_url/score/scorecard/pagename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CI's default routing.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#passing-uri-segments-to-your-methods

```
 public function scorecard($game)
   {
         $this->load->view('/Cricket/'.$game);
   }
```

www.example.com/scores/scorecard/IND_NZ_NOV01

`$game` would equal `'IND_NZ_NOV01'` and the view would load file `Cricket/IND_NZ_NOV01.php`.

Comment: // assume cricketview is a <div> with some formatting.
   $this->load->view('cricketview', $contents);

Comment: so I have to put whole individual page content in <div id=cricketview> ( IND_NZ_NOV01.php,CAN_NK_OCT30_NOV02.php),so after doing this I all pages access by going to individual url.Is it correct.

Comment: @BuntyKumarSharma Sorry, I just re-read your question and this answer is completely wrong! You want individual scorecards on their own pages.

Comment: yes I want individual scorecard on thierown pages site_base_url/scores/scorecard/IND_NZ_NOV01.php
site_base_url/scores/scorecard/ZIM_WI_OCT29_NOV02.php
site_base_url/scores/scorecard/PAKW_NZW_NOV02.php

Comment: How to pass $arpf array value in scorecard method as before I am using $arpf array by include(filename.php) filename.php containing array and passing through view.As                     public function scorecard()
   { include('filename.php');                                                                foreach ($arpf as $page)              { $this->load->view('/Cricket/'.$page); } Now how to pass $arpf in method scorecard($arpf)

Comment: Thanks,Success in loding site_base_url/score/scorecard/pagename

Comment: Can you help in this question  :-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611733/exception-call-to-a-member-function-ruri-string-on-null